# How did Z8000 implement mul/div in few transistors with no microcode?

Tags: cpu, chip, microprocessor, 16-bit, zilog

The Z8000 was Zilog's entry in the 16-bit microprocessor market; it was unsuccessful in large part, as I understand it, because it took too long to debug. According to https://thechipletter.substack.com/p/captain-zilog-crushed-the-story-of

> One key implementation decision was that the Z8000 would not make use of microcode.

Okay. That can be a good decision, if you also keep the instruction set very simple and streamlined; though I had not had the impression the Z8000 was a RISC.

> Intel had also decided on an implementation that used microcode. The 8086 needed more transistors (more than 50% more than the Z8000) for a less impressive design.

Hmm! That does sound like a RISC Z8000, contrary to the impression I previously had.

> THERE’S 32-BIT OPERATION CAPABILITY BUILT INTO THE Z8000 THAT INCLUDES MULTIPLY AND DIVIDE!

... huh??

It's one thing putting multiply and divide instructions in a microprocessor, even in the seventies, if you are using microcode.

It's another thing altogether to do so without microcode!

Are all of the above claims correct? if so, how did the Z8000 manage to end up with fewer transistors than the 8086?

Comment: The technical manual (http://www.bitsavers.org/components/zilog/z8000/Z8000Tech.pdf) strongly suggests that it does looping, at least on the Long Word multiply where the execution times depend on the number of bits equal to one in the destination operand (oddly enough). Whether you consider that 'microcode' or not...

Comment: @JonCuster Right, I wasn't expecting a Wallace/Dadda tree multiplier, not in that transistor budget. But if you have to implement loops in random logic, I thought that still cost more transistors compared to microcode.

Comment: Indeed, I agree. Not finding anything else of relevance in other Z8000 documentation though...

Comment: @njuffa Yeah, presumably so. But I would expect that to take more transistors, not fewer. After all, the whole point of microcode is that it is a transistor-efficient way to implement complex instructions.

Comment: Yes - if you have a bunch of complex instructions to implement - you amortize the microcode store+engine over them.  But if you've got only two - both (complex) arithmetic instructions that basically need stuff you've already got like shifts/add/subract/compare and a counter or two plus some random logic - maybe then random logic suffices at a lower transistor count.

Comment: So they nanocoded the multiply/divide without microcoding the rest.

Comment: @njuffa, a dedicated mul/div can be built more simply without an FSM (finite state machine). A counter, and a 'run' flip-flop plus a small handful of gates can control the mul/div's shift register and add/subtract logic. I've built them in VHDL for FPGAs. And using that relatively tiny control circuit would be worthwhile to keep the overhead of microcode out of it.

Comment: @TonyM congratulations on inventing an FSM

Comment: @njuffa: While counters are a subset of finite state machines, a Johnson counter can be implemented very compactly in silicon because the bit pattern for each state may be very easily be derived from that of the previous state.

Comment: @user253751,...?

Comment: @rwallace _"But if you have to implement loops in random logic, I thought that still cost more transistors compared to microcode."_ Not really. after all, it just repeats the actual operation(step), so all it needs would be a counter, or even more simple a shift register the size of an operand (16 FF for 16 bit), saving the decrementer. If loaded with one of that operand and tested for zero (16 input or) it will even enable looping dependent on content. If we now consider that multiplication done as shift and add already implies shifting, it comes for free.

Comment: @TonyM The definition of an FSM by user253751 is the generic one. Each clocked circuit that goes through finite number of "states" is an FSM. Even a single flip-flop is an FSM by that definition, and so is your mul/div implementation. You don't need a specific form of representation or building block.

Comment: thebusybee, I understand the subject very well but I was asking one user (@user253751) a question as it appears they don't, rather than starting a group discussion.